# Do you know the name of this ghost town movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, mystery

I've been trying to find out the name of a direct to tv movie I watched on cable some years ago, I didn't catch the name of the movie at the time but the plot is something like this:

A family of 4(dad, mom, kid daughter and preteen son) plus the son's best friend go on a trip for a school report for the son. They arrive at a dinner first where everyone looks suspicious but only the daughter takes notice of this. Then they arrive to this abandoned old west town, while everybody is looking around the car disappears and they take refugee on one of the buildings.

Dad and son's best friend go to look for help and decide to cross a desertic area, in this place they find a lot of sand turned to crystal, the dad says that's most likely because the area used to be a weapon test ground. Suddenly the best friend starts to act weird and fall into a dune but when dad reaches to see if he is okay, he had disappeared. Later he reaches a a large dumpster and the car is there.

Meanwhile, mom, daughter and son are in one of the old building waiting, when night arrives. It is implied something is chasing them because we get first person shots of something looking at them. Mom falls into a mine underneath the building and tries to escape, then she sees the thing that is stalking them. We never get a shot of the creature, but it is implied it might be a radioactive mutant. Mom escapes the mine and as soon as she is out the dad arrives. He explains the situation and the family leaves and goes to the closest town.

There they explain their ordeal to the sheriff, who seems to be aware of the mutant and tells the family everything will be okay.

The family stays at a motel and later that night the police tell them they have found the best friend. When they go for him, they find him in a catatonic state and seemingly under the influence of something.

As the family leaves town, the creature slams their car and it crashes. As the camera zooms on the dad as he screams, the scene is changed to day time and we see the family working on the dinner shown at the start of the movie. The daughter goes out and stares at a crow, the crow flies away and the movie ends.

This movie is bad, the plot doesn't make sense at all, you don't know if it's a paranormal movie or a mutant movie or ufo movie. Still, it's so bad it's entertaining.

Comment: Sounds very close to one of "The Hills Have Eyes" series.

Comment: this movie seemed like a low budget movie from the late 90's and early 2000, the acting was bad and no special effects nor make up were used at all. I believe The Hills Have Eyes show the monsters but in this movie no creature was shown at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the TV movie [Disappearance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311018/combined) from 2002. In it, a mom, dad, son and daughter stop at a desert ghost town to snap some photos and are chased by unseen mutants. Every detail you mentioned is there: Their car is stolen, they find glass in the sand and realize this was a test site, mom falls down a mine shaft and there's also a shifty sheriff. In the end, they all work in the diner from the beginning, seemingly lobotomized, and the daughter feeds a crow. Here's the trailer: